# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied

Tags: sharepoint

I encountered an exception when I used c# code to create subdirectories in sharepoint's specified directory.

Exception message:
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

Anybody can help me? thanks!

The following is parameters:

- file: D:\Repos\helpfilesync\ArtefactUploader\bin\Release\ArtefactUploader.exe
- fileName: ArtefactUploader.exe
- uploadPath: /sites/Platform/Shared Documents/dailybuild/helpfilesync/
- subFolderPath: v0.1.0/

  ```
  public void Upload()
  {
      using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("*****"))
      {
          SecureString pass = new SecureString();
          foreach (char ch in password)
          {
              pass.AppendChar(ch);
          }
          clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(user, pass);
          Web web = clientContext.Web;
          clientContext.Load(web);
          clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

          if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.subFolderPath))
          {
              CreateFolder(clientContext.Web, uploadPath, subFolderPath);
          }

          using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
          {
              Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect
                  (clientContext, $"{this.uploadPath}{this.subFolderPath}/{fileName}", fs, true);
          }

          Console.WriteLine("Uploaded File Successfully");
      }
  }

  public void CreateFolder(Web web, string relativePath, string fullFolderPath)
  {
      if (web == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(web));
      }

      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(relativePath))
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(relativePath));
      }

      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fullFolderPath))
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException(fullFolderPath);
      }

      Folder relativeFolder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(relativePath);
      CreateFolderInternal(web, relativeFolder, fullFolderPath);
  }

  public static Folder CreateFolderInternal(Web web, Folder parentFolder, string fullFolderPath)
  {
      var folderUrls = fullFolderPath.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      string folderUrl = folderUrls[0];
      var curFolder = parentFolder.Folders.Add(folderUrl);
      //web.Context.Load(curFolder);
      try
      {
          web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
      }


      if (folderUrls.Length > 1)
      {
          var folderPath = string.Join("/", folderUrls, 1, folderUrls.Length - 1);
          return CreateFolderInternal(web, curFolder, folderPath);
      }

      return curFolder;
  }
  ```

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access
>   denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access
>   this resource.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream
>   responseStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()    at
>   ArtefactUploader.SharepointUploader.CreateFolderInternal(Web web,
>   Folder parentFolder, String fullFolderPath) in
>   D:\Repos\helpfilesync\ArtefactUploader\SharepointUploader.cs:line 96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did test of your code, works fine. Make sure the user/password is correct.

```
class Program
    {

        const string user = "user@teanat.onmicrosoft.com";
        const string password = "password";
        public static void Upload()
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee"))
            {
                SecureString pass = new SecureString();
                foreach (char ch in password)
                {
                    pass.AppendChar(ch);
                }
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(user, pass);
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("a"))
                {
                    CreateFolder(clientContext.Web, "/sites/lee/mydoc2", "childA");
                }

                //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
                //{
                //    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect
                //        (clientContext, $"{this.uploadPath}{this.subFolderPath}/{fileName}", fs, true);
                //}

                Console.WriteLine("Uploaded File Successfully");
            }
        }

        public static void CreateFolder(Web web, string relativePath, string fullFolderPath)
        {
            if (web == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(web));
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(relativePath))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(relativePath));
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fullFolderPath))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(fullFolderPath);
            }

            Folder relativeFolder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(relativePath);
            CreateFolderInternal(web, relativeFolder, fullFolderPath);
        }

        public static Folder CreateFolderInternal(Web web, Folder parentFolder, string fullFolderPath)
        {
            var folderUrls = fullFolderPath.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string folderUrl = folderUrls[0];
            var curFolder = parentFolder.Folders.Add(folderUrl);
            //web.Context.Load(curFolder);
            try
            {
                web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }


            if (folderUrls.Length > 1)
            {
                var folderPath = string.Join("/", folderUrls, 1, folderUrls.Length - 1);
                return CreateFolderInternal(web, curFolder, folderPath);
            }

            return curFolder;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Upload();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This problem is caused by the reconstructor passing in the SharePoint base address while creating clientcontext objects, which is resolved by passing in the SharePoint site address.Thank Lee_MSFT
- Before:
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://****.sharepoint.com")
After:
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***")